# Add a QPushButton on a QMainWindow form with the help of plugin

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I have Qt plugin which should add a QPushButton on a QMainWindow form or just return a pointer to a button.

Here is a plugins' function:

```
 QPushButton* ButPlugin::addButton(QMainWindow* w) const
    {
        QPushButton* but = new QPushButton(" Hello from ButPlugin.dll", w);
        but->setGeometry(70, 70, 150, 150);
        return but;
    }
```

Unfortunatelly, when I try to  `show()` `but`(it doesn't matter, if I call `show()` from the main program or from the plugin), the program do not finish its' work correctly. It faces unhandled exception.

How it can be fixed? Thanks for any ideas

Here is a header file of the plugin:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "PluginInterface.h"
#include "ButPluginInterface.h"
#include <QPushButton>


class ButPlugin : public QObject, public ButPluginInterface, public PluginInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(ButPluginInterface PluginInterface)

public:
    ButPlugin() {};
    ~ButPlugin() {};
    QString Name() const;
    QPushButton* addButton(QMainWindow*) const;
};

#endif // BUTPLUGIN_H
```

ButPlugin.cpp

```
#include "ButPlugin.h"


Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(ButPlugin, ButPlugin)


QString ButPlugin::Name() const
{
    return "ButPlugin";
}

QPushButton* ButPlugin::addButton(QMainWindow* window) const
{
    QPushButton* but = new QPushButton(" Hello from ButPlugin.dll! ", window);
    but->setGeometry(70, 70, 150, 150);
    //but->show();
    return but;
}
```

.pro file of the plugin:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = ButtonPlugin
CONFIG += plugin debug
VERSION = 1.0
DEFINES += VERSION="$$VERSION"
INSTALLS += target
HEADERS += ./mainwindow.h \
    ./Descriptor.h \
    ./PluginInterface.h \
    ./ButPlugin.h \
    ./ButPluginInterface.h
SOURCES += ./main.cpp \
    ./mainwindow.cpp \
    ./ButPlugin.cpp
FORMS += ./mainwindow.ui
RESOURCES += mainwindow.qrc
```

Main application code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow* w = new MainWindow();
    w->show();
    try
    {
        QDir _path(pluginsPath);
        QStringList dllList = _path.entryList(QStringList("*.dll")); 

        foreach (QString fileName, dllList) 
        {
            PossiblePlugin tempPlugin;
            QPluginLoader* loader= new QPluginLoader(_path.absoluteFilePath(fileName));
            QObject* possiblePlugin = loader->instance();
            QObject* tryPlugin = i.value()->_loader->instance();
            if (tryPlugin)
            {
                ButPluginInterface* tempButInt = tryInterface<ButPluginInterface>(tryPlugin);
                if (tempButInt)
                {
                    auto newPlugin = _pluginsList.find(i.key());
                    if (newPlugin == _pluginsList.end())
                        _pluginsList.insert(i.key(), i.value()->_loader);

                    QMainWindow* win = new MainWindow();
                    win->show();
                    QPushButton* bt = nullptr;
                    bt = tempButInt->addButton(win);

                    //bt->setGeometry(20,20,20,20);
                    // when this method was executed
                    // application continues working
                    // and shows warning only when it tries to
                    // do return a.exec();
                    bt->show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        showMsgBox(QString("Unknown error occured"), QString(""), QMessageBox::StandardButton::Cancel);
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

As for .pro file of the main application, there is no .pro file in this project. The program is being developed in MS Visal Studio and Qt libraries is just an add-in. So it runs without .pro file.

MainWindow class was generated by Qt.

MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

Error:
"Unhandled exception at 0x5a1a1a37 (QtCored4.dll) in PluginsManager_3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x5c8f996c."

I suppose there is some troubles with pointer. 
I got all Form children `QObjectList list = win->children();` and it turned out that form knew about this button... 
The exceprtion is thrown only after calling of show() function, if you tries to setGeometry(70, 70, 150, 150); from the main application, it will work properly.

Comment: Please show a minimal, two-file example of the plugin and main application code that reproduces this behavior. Include the .pro files for both.

Comment: Can you print out the actual error message as well, are we talking about a seg fault (possible bad pointer)? You also appear to have multiple MainWindows and a custom "MainWindow" type? The first is of type "MainWindow *" and the second one in the loop is "QMainWindow *". Where is "MainWindow" type defined? What are all these MainWindows for?